# Connect to local CosmosDB emulator from Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-emulator, azure-cosmosdb, azure-storage-emulator

I have a Xamarin app, which use Azure Storage and Azure Cosmos.
For now, both storage are emulated from my PC.
As well as a Pixel 2 from the Android emulator.

I found that I need to configure the ip as 10.0.2.2, even if I can't find this IP or even network on my PC.
Although, it works well with the storage account, I can connect to it.

But when I'm connecting to Cosmos, I get the following exception :

```
Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
 at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.c:1132
```

I'm not an expert in Android, How can I add a custom certificate?

Or just disable SSL for Cosmos emulator?

Comment: If you are trying to write an Android app that directly connects to Cosmos DB I would rethink your design because doing so requires you embed your master keys in the client application which for security reasons is not something you want to do. Mobile and similar applications should first connect to a service layer endpoint that talks to Cosmos DB.

Comment: The app is only for me, to manage my server. No need of security

Comment: You may want to look at this article related to exporting the emulator's SSL cert, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator-export-ssl-certificates